# Eclipse: disable java indexing

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to disable java indexing in eclipse?
My workspace takes about 15 minutes to shut down due to this indexing.
(automatic workspace build...)
I already have tried:
* disable all validators
* web - links : add * to disable the link indexer

Comment: looks like a lot of time. Have you tried closing some unused projects?

Comment: Well, i'm using the workspace in a headless environment. Closing is not an option due to following tasks

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but do you mean you're using eclipse in a machine without a graphical UI? Are you using eclipse as a builder?

Comment: Yes Leo, that's exactly what i'm doing. I'd like to disable the indexing so my workspace can shutdown immediately so the buildtime decreases* by 50pct.

Comment: I didn't even know it was possible :-) I suppose you're following a procedure like this http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_apt_building_with_apt.htm - I am not sure if it's possible. Are you using linux? I've heard about some linux trick to improve eclipse performance, let me find it here

Comment: I'd try moving the JVM to a ramdisk. I've did this once and I think it was fine http://askubuntu.com/questions/112996/good-way-to-run-java-and-eclipse-from-a-ramdisk

Comment: that's not an option... I have to solve it without moving the virtual machine